# Thinking Sphinx Not Recognizing "set_property :min_prefix_len"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, thinking-sphinx

I've been trying to get Thinking Sphinx for Ruby to handle prefixes and/or star, and every time i generate a new configuration file, it seems to ignore it.

Here's the line I added:

```
define_index do
    [... Stuff ...]
    set_property :min_prefix_len => 1
end
```

And then I run:

```
rake ts:config
rake ts:in
rake ts:run
```

And nothing new. I keep checking the config file, and it never changes due to this. I even manually go in and change the file, and then in is replaced with a file without anything relating to min_prefix. Any thoughts?

---

Edit --

I don't have a .yml file right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to the question ended up being:

-Upgrade to more recent version of TS - older versions (<1.3.14) do not support multiple indexes

-The define index blocks need to be setup like this:

```
  define_index 'library_index' do
     [...]
  end

  define_index 'prefix_library_index' do
     [...]
     set_property :min_prefix_len => 1
  end
```

-Calling the search function needs to specify the index or it will search across all indexes -

```
Library.search(keyword, { index => 'prefix_libary_index', <other params here> } )
```

Answer (score 2):

<strike>I've just tested this on my local machine, and it's not working for me either... I'll see if I can find the source of the bug.</strike> My mistake, got the setting key wrong. It actually works fine for me.

So, what version of Thinking Sphinx are you using? What else is in your index definition? Do you have a sphinx.yml file? If so, what's in it?

Also, it's probably worth continuing this discussion on [the Google group](http://groups.google.com/group/thinking-sphinx/) - it's a bit better for back-and-forth debugging.

Comment: Will do... i'll post back here when I find out more.

Comment: Ok, i've upgraded, and now I've added the two index names (index_name 'prefix index') to the define_index statements... here's the response:

ERROR: section 'library_core_0' (type='source') already exists [...]

Comment: You shouldn't need to add index_name directives in your `define_index` blocks.

Comment: you do if you have multiple indexes on the same table